# How do I access the admissions data from College Scorecard?

Tags: api, collegescorecard

I think my api formatting is off, but I keep getting errors from: 
https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?fields=admissions.sat_scores&api_key=redacted

the error is {"errors":[{"error":"field_not_found","input":"admissions.sat_scores","message":"The input field 'admissions.sat_scores' (in the fields parameter) is not a field in this dataset."}]}

Answer (score 1):

Time series data such as the `completion`, `earnings`, `cost`, `admissions`, `student`, `academics`, `aid`, `repayment` metrics are organized within objects relative to each year the data was collected.  We included a `latest` object at the top level of each institution that contains the latest data collected.

Here is an example of an API call that queries the `latest.admissions.sat_scores`:

```
https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?
fields=latest.admissions.sat_scores
&api_key=API_KEY
```